# send data in request body by calling curl using command line arguments

Tags: shell, curl

```
var_createsession=$(curl -H "client_session_id:script.sh" -H "home-id:$home_id" -H "client_id:sample.sh" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"action":"ip","{"\profile\":\"$profile_name\"}","includeBookmark":"false","serviceGroup":41,"accountNumber":"123456","macAddress":"abc"}' -s -w "HTTPSTATUS%{http_code}" "$cmplt_url_createsession")
```

### error description :

> "errorDetail":"Invalid Parameter:JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value; nested exception is >com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n

Can some one help or provide any suggestion to send the request body with multiple data.

Comment: Please format the code in your question.

Comment: You have a typo: `...{"\profile\"...` should be `...{\"profile\"...`.

Comment: Building JSON using string interpolation is also a bad idea. Consider using `jq` or the like to generate the JSON safely.

Comment: Hi chepner,
your suggestion resolved the issue.